# How to replace a column in one table with a column from another table in SQL

Tags: mysql

Table 1 Columns: jobs_id, job_id, customer_id, time

Table 2 columns: customer_id, name

How do I replace the customer_id's from table 1 with the names in Table 2. And then sort the Table 1 by lowest time.

Comment: you don't mean change to the names, as you have no names in T1. You mean a join with an order by

Comment: Ok, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

If it was

```
select t1.jobs_id,t1.job_id,t1.customer_id,t1.time
from table1 t1
order by t1.time
```

it becomes

```
select t1.jobs_id,t1.job_id,t1.customer_id,t1.time,t2.name
from table1 t1
join table2 t2
on t2.customer_id=t1.customer_id
order by t1.time
```

or

```
select t1.jobs_id,t1.job_id,t1.time,t2.name
from table1 t1
join table2 t2
on t2.customer_id=t1.customer_id
order by t1.time
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: my pleasure good luck cdc

Answer (score 1):

There is a relationship between table1 and table2 via the customer_id column. You can join the two tables together in a single query using that relationship to obtain your desired results.

```
SELECT t1.jobs_id, t1.job_id, t1.customer_id, t2.name, t1.time
    FROM table1 t1
        INNER JOIN table2 t2
            ON t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
    ORDER BY t1.time;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) to join the information in multiple tables together based on some relationship, usually they share the same key like `customer_id`.

```
SELECT name
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table2.customer_id = table1.customer_id
ORDER BY table1.time
```

This says "for every row in table1, go find the row with the matching customer_id in table 2".  Now you can work with columns from both tables.

JOINs are one of the most important strengths of a relational database.  Here's [a good visual representation of the different types](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins).